# Always executes else clause even if value present in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
    if($result==$var)
    {
     echo "tracking id present in the manifest</br>";
    }
     else
    {
      echo "trackingid not present<br>";
      exit(0);
    }
```

When i retrieve data from database and check it against the data i have entered,even though the data entered is correct and present in the database it executes the else clause.where am i going wrong? please help!

Comment: whats the value of $var

Comment: $var is the awb_no i am entering in the text field.

Comment: `$result` contains all the columns returned by the query. So, it's not same as `$var`. You need to extract the `awb_no` from the query using the `column name` and than compare it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice prerak, but can you give me an example! would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to count the rows from your query so try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "tracking id present in the manifest</br>";
} else {
    echo "trackingid not present<br>";
    exit(0);
}
```

Btw `mysql` is depricated so use `PDO` or `mysqli`